# Getting frame parent origin/details

Tags: javascript

I'm inside a frame and I'm trying to get the href/host/origin of the parent page via `window.parent.location`. If I just `console.log(window.parent.location);` I get a nice object with all details I want but if I try to use `window.parent.location.origin` or `window.parent.location.href` for example I get an error: `Permission denied to access property 'origin'`.

Any idea why I can see the whole object but can't use any of it's properties?

Comment: If the parent on the same domain?

Comment: No it's not. I know about the 'same origin issue' but I wonder why I can still see the full object.

Comment: Maybe a bug? Did you try different browsers?

Comment: Sure. Tried with chrome and ff